# Copy/paste and creating folder in android

Tags: android, file, directory, copy-paste

I want to copy file from one folder to the other folder (for example : sdcard0/folder1/a.text  to sdcard0/folder2 ). I have seen a lot of sample code in this site and other sites but non of them work for me . I don't know where is my problem. I also add permission to the manifest file.
what should I do?
I have several method for this, that I named them from copy1 to copy3 .

```
      //----------Method 1
 public void copy1(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}

 //----------Method 2
public void copy2(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}

 //----------Method 3
    public static boolean copy3(File source, File dest){
    try{
            // Declaration et ouverture des flux
            java.io.FileInputStream sourceFile = new java.io.FileInputStream(source);

            try{
                    java.io.FileOutputStream destinationFile = null;

                    try{
                            destinationFile = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                            // Lecture par segment de 0.5Mo
                            byte buffer[] = new byte[512 * 1024];
                            int nbLecture;

                            while ((nbLecture = sourceFile.read(buffer)) != -1){
                                    destinationFile.write(buffer, 0, nbLecture);
                            }
                    } finally {
                            destinationFile.close();
                    }
            } finally {
                    sourceFile.close();
            }
    } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false; // Erreur
    }

    return true; // Résultat OK
```

}

and I use them like this:
                String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File f= new File(path +"/folder1/a.txt");
                File f2= new File(path+"/folder2/" );
                try{
                  copy1(f,f2);
                }
                catch(Exception e){}

and also for creating Directory  :

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
            File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AAAli");
            if(!dir.exists()) {                                 
                dir.mkdirs(); // build directory
            }
```

Comment: show your code which you have tried

Comment: Help me. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/yourFolder1/yourFile.png";
            File source = new File(sourcePath);

            String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/yourFolder2/yourFile.png";
            File destination = new File(destinationPath);
            try 
            {
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I find this class and add it to my project. but I get this error   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Comment: right click to project and add jar to build export path

Comment: I added the jar files. But it's same.

Comment: I tried to add screenshot but I can't because of my reputation